# Simple Hypergeometric Probability Question--Selecting 2 things out of 3 tries

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question says that there are 25 companies, 5 are bankrupt (0.2 chance of randomly picking a bankrupt company). If an analyst randomly selects 3 companies, what is the probability of 2 of them being bankrupt? I tried to do it but am not very confident with my answer:

I did- ${5 \choose 2}{20 \choose 1} / {25 \choose 3} = 0.0037$ [*]

Because you're picking 2 out of a group of 5 and 1 out of a group of 20, all divided by the possible combinations. Any thoughts? Appreciate the help.

Edit: yes, it is when exactly 2 are bankrupt. Also I re-calculated and got a more realistic answer, 2/23 [* not shown above]. Thoughts?

Comment: Hint:  suppose the three companies he picks are $A,B,C$.  What is the probability that $A$ and $B$ are bankrupt, but $C$ isn't?  How many other configurations do you need to consider?

Comment: Note: I am assuming (possibly incorrectly) that the problem means "exactly $2$ of them are bankrupt".  If instead the problem meant "at least $2$ of them are bankrupt" then you have to be sure to consider the case where all three of them are defunct.

Comment: @lulu should I approach this as a joint probability or as a permutation/combination problem?

Comment: A bit of each. For the exact case I mentioned, you just want three events to happen simultaneously.  Then you need to count the scenarios that contribute.

Comment: @lulu so you think I should make it .8*.2*.2? Why should I do this instead of thinking it as me picking 3 marbles and 2 of them being red if there are 5 red marbles in a jar of 25.

Comment: No...the odds change as you go down the list.  You can do it combinatorially if you prefer, I was just suggesting one method that works.  It is probably good practice to work the exercise both ways.

Comment: Just to be clear, the probability that he chooses Bad, Bad, Good is $\frac 5{25}\times \frac 4{24}\times \frac {20}{23}$.  i am, of course, assuming that he chooses three different companies.

Comment: Awesome thanks man

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** (It seems you have worked out the correct answer with @lulu's assistance, but I didn't want to leave this incomplete and with an incorrect answer still showing in the Question.)

The number $X$ of bankrupt companies in this situation has a *hypergeometric
distribution*, which may be covered in your textbook.

$$P(X = 2) = \frac{{5\choose 2}{20 \choose 1}}{25 \choose 3} = \frac{200}{2300} 
=  0.08696.$$

Here is the PDF of that distribution (as computed in R statistical software):

```
x = 0:3;  pdf = dhyper(x, 5, 20, 3)
cbind(x, pdf)
     x         pdf
##   0 0.495652174
##   1 0.413043478
##   2 0.086956522  ## <-- Your Answer
##   3 0.004347826
```

Here is a graph of the PDF with $P(X = 2)$ emphasized in red.

[image]